# "when" condition is not working while dynamically including file

Tags: ansible

I am trying to `include` file dynamically on the basis of parameter passed in `ansible-playbook`. To validate parameter I am checking it in `when` condition but its suppose to not working for me. *Its checking include file first.*

**playbook.yml:-**

```
---
- hosts: local
  user: roop
  gather_facts: no

  vars: {action: "",validAction: ["action1","action2","action3","action4"]}

  tasks:

    - name: validate action
      fail: msg="please make sure you pass valid action"
      when: action == "" or action not in validAction

    - include: "action/{{ action }}.yml"
      when: action !="" and action in validAction
```

These are two cases:

1) When action is not passed in parameter

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR: file not found: /path/to/action/.yml
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Should be execute task 1 "Validate action" first.
```

2)  When action is wrong

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "action=action5"
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR: file not found: /path/to/action/action5.yml
```

**Expected Output:**

when user pass action which is not valid action then it should check in task1 `entity not in validEntity` . in first task if condition are not valid then it should abort the executions.

any suggestions to handle this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that ansible does a pre checks of include before it run the function `parse_yaml_from_file` is called and that fails if no file is on FS

As a workaround you can use the following code, but you might want to report that on Ansible github as a feature request.

Please create a **dummy.yml** under the directory action for the code below to work `touch action/dummy.yml`

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  vars: 

     action      : ""
     dummy       : "{{ action if action in validAction else 'dummy' }}"
     validAction : ["action1","action2","action3","action4"]

  tasks:
   - include: "action/{{dummy}}.yml"
```

Comment: My validation task are working perfectly but its doesn't change value of dummy variable. I means to say its including `dummy.yml` every time

Comment: That section sets the action variable {% set dummy=action %}... did  you remove that part ?

Comment: Which part I need to remove? I am using same code as suggested by you. action variable value are not changing . I have checked by adding `- debug: var=dummy` before `include` task. its always showing `dummy.yml`. When `action=action1` it should include `action1.yml`

Comment: Its working perfect !! Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Is it possible `elseif` condition is playbook some like this `"{{ action if action in validAction <variable> elseif <somecondition> else 'dummy' }}"`??

Comment: That should be a different question. But yes you can check for if syntax http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#if instead of 'elseif' use'elif'

Comment: @DomanNitro I have added my new query as [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264226/how-to-write-dynamic-variable-in-ansible-playbook)