# How to write dynamic variable in Ansible playbook

Tags: jinja2, ansible

Based on `extra vars` parameter I Need to write variable value in `ansible playbook`

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e "param1=value1 param2=value2 param3=value3"
```

If only **param1** passed

```
myvariable: 'param1'
```

If only **param1,param2** passed

```
myvariable: 'param1,param2'
```

If **param1,param2,param3** are passed then variable value will be

```
myvariable: 'param1,param2,param3'
```

When I try to create variable dynamically through template then my playbook always takes previous variable value. But inside  `dest=roles/myrole/vars/main.yml` its writing correct value.

What I make a try here

```
- hosts: local
  user: roop
  gather_facts: yes
  connection: local

  tasks: 

  - template: src=roles/myrole/templates/myvar.j2 dest=roles/myrole/vars/main.yml

  - debug: var=myvariable

  roles:
        - { role: myrole }
```

So inside **myrole** directory I have created `template` and `vars`

```
- roles
  - myrole
    - vars/main.yml
    - templates/myvar.j2
```

**templates/myvar.j2**

```
{% if param1 is defined and param2 is defined and param3 is defined %}
  myvariable: 'param1,param2,param3'
{% elif param1 is defined and param2 is defined %}
  myvariable: 'param1,param2'
{% elif param1 is defined %}
  myvariable: 'param1'
{% else %}
  myvariable: 'default-param'
{% endif %}
```

As I know if only two condition then I can do this using `inline expression` like below

```
{{ 'param1,param2' if param1 is defined and param2 is defined else 'default-param' }}
```

`<do something> if <something is true> else <do something else>`

Is it possible `if - elif - else` in `inline expression` like above. Or any other way to assign value dynamically in ansible playbook?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I am sure there is a smarter way for doing what you want but this should work:

```
- name         : Test var
  hosts        : all
  gather_facts : no
  vars:
    myvariable : false
  tasks:
    - name: param1
      set_fact:
        myvariable: "{{param1}}"
      when: param1 is defined

    - name: param2
      set_fact:
        myvariable: "{{ param2 if not myvariable else myvariable + ',' + param2 }}"
      when: param2 is defined

    - name: param3
      set_fact:
        myvariable: "{{ param3 if not myvariable else myvariable + ',' + param3 }}"
      when: param3 is defined

    - name: default
      set_fact:
        myvariable: "default"
      when: not myvariable

    - debug:
       var=myvariable
```

Hope that helps. I am not sure if you can construct variables dynamically and do this in an iterator. But you could also write a small python code or any other language and plug it into ansible

Comment: @Roopendra 16 lines of code to concatenate a list of 3 values is far from nice.

Comment: Agreed @ceving but sometimes we focus on solution and then later optimisation.  That time this was the only solution. I will happy if you will share optimised answer. Maybe it will helps to other folks as well.

Comment: Say you have 100 hosts, this fact will be set 100 times for each host even if the value will remain same for all the hosts. You could a variable, which will set a single global fact.

Answer (score 41):

my_var: the variable declared

VAR: the variable, whose value is to be checked

param_1, param_2: values of the variable VAR

value_1, value_2, value_3: the values to be assigned to my_var according to the values of my_var

```
my_var: "{{ 'value_1' if VAR == 'param_1' else 'value_2' if VAR == 'param_2' else 'value_3' }}"
```

Answer (score 21):

I would first suggest that you step back and look at organizing your plays to not require such complexity, but if you really really do, use the following:

```
   vars:
    myvariable: "{{[param1|default(''), param2|default(''), param3|default('')]|join(',')}}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Getting output `",,"` after changing myvariable as suggested by you.

Comment: Try with [`reject`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#reject) and [`tests`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#builtin-tests): `{{ [param1, param2, param3, param4]|reject('undefined')|join(',') }}`